# VMWare Virtual Storage Appliance 5.1: Network clarification

Tags: vmware-esxi, storage-area-network

After bludgeoning my way through a vanilla two-node VSA installation ("Greenfield"), I have a VSA setup with no machines running at the moment; just trying to get my head around how the network is configured.

You can see what the network is configured as here (borrowed from a VMWare blog post, but looks the same):
[image: VMware VSA network configuration]

Caveat: what makes my deployment slightly more non-standard is the use of Emulex Flex NICs that handle the VLAN tagging within the firmware itself, so no tagging is taking place in ESXi natively, I just assign pre-tagged, pre-carved-up "virtual" interfaces to the corresponding pNIC/uplink/vSwitch accordingly.

Where I need clarification revolves around the fact that I have 8 physical NICs per (two) ESXi hosts; obviously I'd like to use them all.  However, all documentation I've seen for VSA centers around a 4-NIC (2 x 2 GbE) configuration.

Questions as follows:

1. I want to add another VM Network and remove/rename the pre-created/default VM Network to assign it to another virtual switch with a different pNIC (see above).

   From what I can tell from the Summary tab, the "VSA-01" and "VSA-02" VSA virtual machines are only configured with the "VSA-Front End" and "VSA-Back End" networks; removing the "VM Network" from vSwitch0 should have no impact, nor should creating any other virtual machine networks on new vSwitches.  Does this sound about right?
2. I see there's a "VSA-VMotion" port group.  Is this for VSA-related VMotion activities only, or is this also used for "normal" VMotion moves between the two ESXi hosts in the cluster?

Comment: were you not tempted to use the VSAN feature with vSphere 5.5? I know it's still technically in beta but it's as stable as VSA and will replace it once it's released.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Regarding 4 vs 8 pNICs**.  Your current (ASA derived) configuration binds x2 pNICs to vSwitch0 and x2 pNICs to vSwitch1.  There is absolutely nothing stopping you adding two more pNICs each to your existing vSwitches, to give you utilisation over the whole of 8 pNICs.  As long as the additional pNICs are configured to carry the same VLANs as the existing ones, there is no problem with this approach.

Answers to your questions:

**(1)** This should not cause any issues. You can rename/delete the default VM network, just check none of your VMs are using it first.  According to your screenshot, nothing is using "VM Network" currently, so you are safe to alter it.

**(2)** The VMotion port group created by VSA installer is for use by both VSA-VMs and your "normal" VMotion moves.

*Note1: you appear to have management and VMotion on the same VLAN, "best practice" (whatever you take that to mean) is to separate this traffic onto different VLANS.*

*Note2: you probably don't want your VMs and management/VMotion interfaces sharing the same VLAN ID 1955, so you should separate them.*

Answer derived from:

http://www.vmware.com/files/pdf/techpaper/VM-vSphere-Storage-Appliance-Deep-Dive-WP.pdf

Comment: Thanks.  I ended up redoing the VSA cluster and pre-configured the network as I wanted it and the VSA installation was successful; why the VSA creates this as default (vMotion/Management on same VLAN, VSA-Back End on a separate switch), I have no idea; Deep Dive suggested "costs/complexity" but honestly, you're buying the redundant switches regardless, how much more is it to throw a quad NIC in your hosts?  Should've standardized on an 8-NIC configuration , not 4, is what I'm saying.  Maybe new version of VSA in 5.5 will be different in that regard.